# How can i create only one record with Hibernate JPA Annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have got 3 entity. These are: Tweet,Thread and Media. I am using Hibernate JPA Annotations. When i save one Thread object, it must trigger to tweet and automatically tweet must saved like thread and Tweet's "media" must saved of course.

You can see my entity class as below. Right now i'm working on Tweet beetween Thread. When i use these code, The number of thread is being recorded as much as tweet object. But i want that **only one record inside thread**.

Process must be like that after saved **thread**:

1. add a new record to Thread table. (only one row)
2. add all tweet to tweet table(all of "threadid" column **same** because these tweets belong only one thread!)
3. add all media to media table(all of "tweetid" column **same** )

Tweet Table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_tweet")
public class Tweet implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "tweetid")
    private String tweetID;
    private String parentTweetID;
    private String avatar;
    private String owner_name;
    private String owner_nick;
    private String content;
    private String sent_time;
    private String sent_date;
    private String retweet_count;
    private String like_count;
    private String owner_link;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="threadid")
    private Thread thread;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tweet",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Media> mediaURLs;
```

Thread Table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_thread")
public class Thread implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;
        @Column(name = "threadid")
        private String threadID;

        @Transient
        private List<Tweet> listOfTweets;
```

Media Table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_media")
public class Media implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String mediaID;
    private String mediaType;
    private String mediaUrl;
    private String mediaUrlHttps;
    private String mediaVideoUrl;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tweetid")
    private Tweet tweet;
```

My expected and actual results:
http://prntscr.com/mkaul5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed that way. Right now it's working good. Long live annotations!

Tweet Table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_tweet")
public class Tweet implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Column(unique = true,nullable = false,name = "tweetID")
    private String tweetID;
    private String parentTweetID;
    private String avatar;
    private long owner_id;
    private String owner_name;
    private String owner_nick;
    private String content;
    private String sent_time;
    private String sent_date;
    private String retweet_count;
    private String like_count;
    @Transient
    private String quotedTweetHtml;
    @Transient
    @JoinColumn(name = "threadid",referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Thread thread;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tweetID")
    private List<Media> mediaURLs;
```

Thread Table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_thread")
public class Thread implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;
        @Column(name = "threadid")
        private String threadID;
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "threadid")
        private List<Tweet> listOfTweets;
```

Media Table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_media")
public class Media implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String mediaID;
    private String mediaType;
    private String mediaUrl;
    private String mediaUrlHttps;
    private String mediaVideoUrl;
    @Transient
    @JoinColumn(name = "tweetID")
    private Tweet tweet;
```